# use FFMpeg to send BMPs to stdout

Tags: ffmpeg, command-line-arguments

I see lots of examples using FFMpeg to make a video file from a set of images. I can also see how to do the opposite if I want individual files. However, I want the images to be pushed to stdout. This line fails:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i Wildlife.wmv -pix_fmt bgr24 -an -sn -f bmp - > junk.bin
```

It says "Requested output format 'bmp' is not a suitable output format". However, this line works fine to generate image files:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i Wildlife.wmv -pix_fmt bgr24 -an -sn test%03d.bmp
```

How can I get images pushed to stdout?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that in ffmpeg, BMP is not a file format. It's an encoder (as seen under `ffmpeg -encoders`). Normal BMP files can be written with the [`image2` muxer](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#image2-2), but if you only want the raw video codec, you need the `rawvideo` format.

So, use something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.wmv -c:v bmp -f rawvideo -an - > output.bin
```

Comment: Further discussion of this exact issue [here](https://superuser.com/a/1248340/459921).

Comment: Followup question to your helpful answer... what's the difference between the `image2` and `image2pipe` muxers in **ffmpeg**?

Comment: @GlennSlayden `image2` reads from actual files specified by filename; `image2pipe` reads from a pipe, that is, images piped via STDIN.

Comment: Yes, sorry, my question should have been, why are separate binaries needed for that when external piping of stdin and/or stdout should be transparent to any program?

Comment: @GlennSlayden Not sure I understand. You don't need separate binaries – just one `ffmpeg`. `image2pipe` is a fairly simple demuxer part of the `image2` code, whereas `image2` needs additional capabilities to deal with filenames.