# Ffmpeg - save bmp file as different extension

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, png, libav, bmp

I want to save a `bmp` file as `1.mp4` using Ffmpeg, how to achieve it?

The question is very simple. I have some source file, lets call it `source.png` and I want to encode it as `bmp`, but to save it as a file with extension `mp4`. Of course, one way to achieve it is to save it as file with `bmp` extension and then use command line to rename it to `mp4`. But, that is not what I want. I want it directly to be saved as `mp4`.

I searched on internet and I found that in order to achieve it, one should specify `-f` parameter. This is my command line:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -i source.png -f bmp 1.mp4
```

And, of course, I got an error `Requested output format 'bmp' is not a suitable output format.`. I continued searching for solution and I found that calling Ffmpeg with parameter `-formats` displays all supported formats. I did it and I found only one format containing word `bmp`:

```
D  bmp_pipe        piped bmp sequence
```

Then I replaced `-f bmp with`-f bmp_pipe`, but again I got the same error. So, how to properly do it?

**In general, my question is:** given extension (for example `bmp` in this case), how to determine the word which needs to be placed after `-f` in order to encode like that extension is present?

---

Maybe I was not clear enough in the question. I'm looking for a way to find the connection between extension (`bmp`, `png`, `mp4`, `avi`, etc) and the Ffmpeg parameter I need to pass in order to encode to that extension.

Basically, I'm creating a user interface application where:

1. User enters extension (for example `mp4`)
2. User enters output file name (for example `C:\1.exe` (just a dumb example))
3. I need to spawn ffmpeg process which will encode input file like output file is in that extension which user specified

I hope it is more clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to go through the parent muxer for image sequences, `image2`:

```
ffmpeg -i in.png -c:v bmp -vframes 1 -f image2 out.mp4
```

Run ffmpeg `-muxers` to get a list of available `-f` values. There's no central list of extensions linked to muxers.

Comment: Hm.. Does it apply in general? I mean, I'm searching for a way to ask user for extension and then to encode image (or video) to that extension (but output file is always named `.mp4`) So, can I replace `-c:v bmp` with any other extension and it will work?

Comment: For image formats, this is the method. For video formats, supply `-f ext`

Comment: I updated the question. So, to summarize, for all image extensions, i need to pass `-c:v ext -f image2` and for all video formats I need to pass `-f ext`, right? Are there any exceptions?

Comment: I mean, it is not hard to create two separate lists: one with image extensions and other with video extensions, but I'm just wondering are there any exceptions?

Comment: Not all extensions work as `-f values`. MKV for instance invokes `-f matroska`. For JPEG, you can just use `-f singlejpeg`. There are dozens of formats, so not possible to note all possible exceptions, but among major formats, those are it.

Comment: Sorry if my questions are borring, but I still believe here must be an easy way to do it. For example, when you omit the `-f` parameter, then Ffmpeg determine the right format according to the extension of the output file, right? So, therefore they use some algorithm to do so. I just want Ffmpeg to behave like specific extension is provided no matter what real extension of the output file is.

Comment: There's no way to do it automatically because ffmpeg isn't designed to behave as if the output extension is a false flag. That's a very atypical and unanticipated use case, especially considering you can just rename the file afterwards.

Comment: *"ffmpeg isn't designed to behave as if the output extension is a false flag."* - But what if I want to stream it to another process (our output to stdout) in specific format? For example, I want to encode given file in specific extension (using ffmpeg), then stream to another process and encode it, and save it. So, ffmpeg will not save to file, instead it will stream data to another process, and how to deal with it? Where did you find that `matroska` is for `mkv` and `singlejpeg` for `jpg`? Where I can find these patterns? I need to make this automatic.

Comment: If you're streaming it, and the output URI has no extension, then you have to specify `-f`. Run `ffmpeg -muxers` to get a list of available `-f` values. There's no central list of extensions linked to muxers.

Comment: @user769083 [Here's](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Stream-handling) the relevant part of the doc; it's quite hard to find: "Stream handling is independent of stream selection, with an exception for subtitles described below. Stream handling is set via the `-codec` option addressed to streams within a specific output file. In particular, codec options are applied by **ffmpeg** *after the stream selection process and thus do not influence the latter*. If no `-codec` option is specified for a stream type, **ffmpeg** will select the default encoder registered by the output file muxer."